# What test to use for antibiotics resistance?

Tags: statistics, chi-squared, p-value

I have 23 samples of milk and 14 samples of cheese. For each of the 7 antibiotics there is a given number of samples that were resistant to it. Note there is only a single strain of bacteria.

[image]

Which method should I use to answer these questions?

**TLDR: Is (each of) the given antibiotic more effective against cheese bacteria, milk bacteria, or is there no statistical difference at p=0.05?**

Another way to put it:

For each antibiotic (and at p=0.05):

1. Are bacteria in milk sample more resistant to given antibiotic than bacteria in cheese sample?
2. Are bacteria in cheese sample more resistant to given antibiotic than bacteria in milk sample?
3. Or is there no statisticaly significant difference in the resistance to the given antibiotic between milk and cheese samples?

I think I only need to count p-values somehow. The problem is the different number of samples. Could I use standardized mean difference (Cohen's d) to overcome  this?

Comment: Since there are multiple antibiotics you are testing, define what you mean by "more resistant to antibiotics".  Is it to every one of your antibiotics?  To strictly larger subset of those antibiotics for every sample?  Or just a shear number of antibiotics across samples?  I can't imagine you run all $37\times 2^7$ trials (cocktails on every sample).

Comment: @user10354138 I have clarified the question.

Comment: @Slazer you can use a $\chi^2$ test. Post the entire problem with data if you want more details about the possible solution

Comment: @tommik I have done so.

Comment: @Slazer : in the meantime I guessed 2 examples, See my solution. For your data, for each antibiotics construct the tables as I showed and apply the test. Note that you can apply $\chi^2$ test only if any cell contains at least 5 observation (also 3 or 4 are accepted as borderline test). If there is at least one cell with 0,1 or 2 observation you cannot apply this test and you have to do something else...there are several possible ways to solve this problem

Comment: @tommik By "something else" you mean...? Thank you.

Comment: @Slazer I mean other tests for testing independence like Spearman's $\rho$, Kendall's $\tau$, for a non parametric test or, If you can assume normality, a Student's t test for difference of means for a parametric test.

Comment: @Slazer I added the solution for your OFX antibiotics where the $\chi^2$ test can be applied

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120079/discussion-between-slazer-and-tommik).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing that 5 of the 6 listed antibiotics contain too few observations in the contingency table, one cannot use the chi-square test. When 5 or less observations are present, you have to use the **Fisher's exact test** instead.

https://www.statology.org/fishers-exact-test-excel/
https://youtu.be/p2c4C2D7ZZc